# SQL SELECT multiple SUM() error

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum, left-join

I am having a problem involving multiple `SUM()` functions in a SQL `SELECT` statement using `JOIN`s.

Whenever I sum together two values, it makes the value inside the other sum function double. How do I prevent this?

Example: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2ab82/2) - all X and Y values should be a 2.

I am using SQLite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `UNION` for this:

```
SELECT id, SUM(bamount) AS BAmount, SUM(camount) AS CAmount
FROM
(
  SELECT a.id, SUM(b.amount) AS bamount, 0  AS camount
  FROM a 
  LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id 
  GROUP BY a.id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.id, 0, SUM(c.amount)  AS camount
  FROM a
  LEFT JOIN c ON a.id = c.a_id 
  GROUP BY a.id
) AS t
GROUP BY id;
```

[updated demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2ab82/21)

This will give you:

```
| id | BAmount | CAmount |
|----|---------|---------|
|  1 |       2 |       2 |
|  2 |       2 |       2 |
|  3 |       2 |       2 |
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but this version seems to be more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

You can try performing the aggregations in separate subqueries.  This is one way to get around the problem of double (or triple, etc.) counting rows as the result of a join.

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    t1.b_sum AS x,
    t2.c_sum AS y
FROM a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT a_id, SUM(amount) AS b_sum
    FROM b
    GROUP BY a_id
) t1
    ON a.id = t1.a_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT a_id, SUM(amount) AS c_sum
    FROM c
    GROUP BY a_id
) t2
    ON a.id = t2.a_id;
```